# Don't trigger Angular Reactive Form Validation when Touched

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Reactive form with a single input field that is required.  When a user clicks in this field and clicks away, it triggers the validation and shows the field has red as it has failed validation.

How do I control when validation takes places?  I only wish for it to check validation when a user hits Enter or clicks the button icon next to the field.

I tried to add updateOn: 'blur' or updateOn: 'submit' to the formControl which seemed to work to not show validation when just clicking on the field.  However, this also caused the form to show as "not valid" when clicking the button icon even if there was text in the field.

Here is a working example of the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-pfvuex?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Component File**

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" #empFormDirective="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Add a topic</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          placeholder="I wish to discuss..."
          (keyup)="handleKeyUp($event, 'emp', empFormDirective)"
          formControlName="empTopic"
        />
        <mat-error *ngIf="empTopic.errors?.required && empTopicSubmitted"
          >Topic must not be empty.</mat-error
        >
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-button (click)="onAddEmpTopic($event, empFormDirective)">
        <mat-icon>note_add</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </form>
```

**TypeScript File**

```
empForm = this.fb.group({
empTopic: ['', { validators: [Validators.required] }]
```

})

Comment: `However, this also caused the form to show as "not valid" when clicking the button icon even if there was text in the field.` This shouldn't happen, there must be something weird going on with your code, please provide a [mcve] as I couldn't reproduce the issue when trying your code in a stackblitz (guessing the code that you have not presented...)

Comment: I've updated the section above with a StackBlitz that shows a reproducible example

Comment: OK, so you have put the `onBlur` on the formcontrol, **not** the formgroup as you say in your question.

Comment: Check the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: Thanks for the info on ErrorStateMatcher.  Trying to implement it here with limited success:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-s1ikhd?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/custom-state-matcher.ts

However, now the error doesn't show up at all when I hit "enter" or when I click the "add" button.  Do I have the right conditions on the CustomErrorStateMatcher?

Comment: If you want to display error when form is submitted and if it's invalid, those are two conditions you need to check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-f4xn2x?devtoolsheight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-state-matcher.ts so`form.submitted && control.invalid`

Comment: Also remember that since you are using `reset` after successful submit, it again shows the validation errors, that is just how angular material works, not related to current question.

Comment: Got the ErrorStateMatcher working successfully!  Thank you!  I have a new problem with the form being submitted twice but I've opened a new question here for that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70134622/angular-reactive-form-submits-twice-and-shows-invalid-error-message-after-succes

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom validator function to behave the way you expect it to.

```
export const customValidator: ValidatorFn = () => {
   return (control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null => {
     if(control.touched && !control.value) {
       return { invalid: true };
     }
     return null;
   }
}
```

Update your component code to use this validator instead:

```
  empForm = this.fb.group({
    empTopic: ['', { validators: [customValidator] }]
   });

  handleKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.onAddEmpTopic(e);
    }
  }

  onAddEmpTopic(e) {
    this.empTopic.markAsTouched();
    this.empTopic.updateValueAndValidity();
    if (!this.empForm.valid) {
      console.log('not valid!');
      return;
    }

    console.log('Add a topic!');
    this.empForm.reset();
  }
```

Comment: Working on this Custom Validator here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-3xggzh?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)  .  How would you make sure it only triggers when the user only hits enter on the input field or clicks the "add" icon.

Comment: @DanielMcIntyre updated the code above